# persist the connection object on page change

Tags: javascript, jquery, strophe

I have multiple HTML pages and one JavaScript file which is responsible for making `strophe` connection with the server. All my HTML files are using the same Javascript. But when I move from one page to another page the `connection` object gets `null`

For example, I have create a connection in my `global.js` file in a object `MYPro.connection` 
but when I shift from one HTML page to another `MYPro.connection` gets null.

Is there any way to preserve the object either using JavaScript or jQuery? When I was using jQuery mobile it was working fine but in simple jQuery it's not working that way.

**Note:**
For some reason I am not using jQuery mobile and shifting to only simple jQuery

What i am doing is as follows on page load and in unload i am calling `conn.pause()`

```
     var conn = new Strophe.Connection(

               'http://mydomain.com/http-bind');

     conn.attach( localStorage.currentJID , localStorage.SID , localStorage.RID,function(status){

    if(status === Strophe.Status.ATTACHED){

          // load roster

    }


});
```

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest you to use `HTML5`. You could store data in `localStorage. which will persist data even after refreshing your page and among multiple pages.

I have a working example of `localStorage`on [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/HMEVd/127/).

Short example is here.

```
//Note that if you are writing a userscript, it is a good idea
// to prefix your keys, to reduce the risk of collisions with other 
// userscripts or the page itself.
var prefix = "localStorageDemo-";
$("#save").click(function () { 
var key = $("#key").attr('value');
var value = $("#value").attr('value');
localStorage.setItem(prefix + key, value);      //******* setItem()
//localStorage[prefix+key] = value; also works
RewriteFromStorage();
});

function RewriteFromStorage() {
$("#data").empty();
for(var i = 0; i < localStorage.length; i++)    //******* length
{
    var key = localStorage.key(i);              //******* key()
    if(key.indexOf(prefix) == 0) {
        var value = localStorage.getItem(key);  //******* getItem()
        //var value = localStorage[key]; also works
        var shortkey = key.replace(prefix, "");
        $("#data").append(
            $("<div class='kvp'>").html(shortkey + "=" + value)
               .append($("<input type='button' value='Delete'>")
                       .attr('key', key)
                       .click(function() {      //****** removeItem()
                            localStorage.removeItem($(this).attr('key'));
                            RewriteFromStorage();
                        })
                      )
        );
    }
  }
}

RewriteFromStorage();
```

Hope it helps...!!!

Comment: and what about NON HTML 5 browser ?

Comment: and i guess localStorage only stores string not the connection object itself

Comment: Correct...But you could `parse` your `Object` into a `jSon` object and store it using `localStorage` and to answer your query regarding non HTML 5 browsers i would assume you won't be using less than IE 7 browser..!!!

Comment: You are using simple HTML Pages right...and HTML will work on your Mobile app as well....And `Json` and `HTML5` are regardless of any platform...Infect they will make your mobile app more better and as per market standards...

Comment: Also see a working example of mobile app using html 5 and local storage is here...http://docs.appery.io/tutorials/building-hello-world-app-with-html5-local-storage/

Comment: i am getting Uncaught `TypeError: Converting circular structure to JSON ` i dont think i will be able to store connection object like this

Comment: How you are trying to convert your `Object` into `JSON`.....?? You could make a `JSON` string manually by looping etc. and store it into local storage...

Comment: `localStorage.setItem("IMCON" , JSON.stringify(MYPro.connection));` this how i store

Comment: the strange thing is there when i use jquery mobile i dont even need to persist the object but when i go plain jquery it doesnt

Comment: I can not say without seeing your type of `MYPro.connection`. You could keep it into a JSON itself..

Comment: Jquery Mobile uses HTML 5 full features...thus as per my belief it must be storing using local storage...not sure just assuming..that's why it will work fine when with jquery mobile..

Comment: even i really don't know as when i use jquery mobile , i dont see any values `localStorage` in a chrome , so hard to say how its handling inside

Comment: i guess i am changing page using `window.location` is this the reason why thats happening , do you know anyother way to change a page in javascript or jquery

Comment: This is how window.location works ...see examples..

// similar behavior as an HTTP redirect
window.location.replace("http://stackoverflow.com");

// similar behavior as clicking on a link
window.location.href = "http://stackoverflow.com", 
And i do not see any reasons your Stringfy doesn't work...You could store it in JSOn and it will work like a charm..

Answer (score 0):

You have to store your RID (storage/cookies/etc) and use the attach feature when you load a new page. Don't forget to increment your RID.

```
conn = new Strophe.Connection(xmppserver);
conn.attach(JID, SID, RID, onConn);
```

Comment: do u know from where i can get the SID and RID ?

Comment: The SID is created and returned from the jabber server when you initially connect. If you connect using Strophe, it'll create it for you. If you connect via BOSH, you can create it (random int).

Comment: i had to pause the connection first using `connection.pause` and then `attach` this way its working sometimes only. do i need to install `punjab connection manager`

Comment: Not sure why you would need to pause a connection that's not established. Are you doing something else before attaching? How are you calling starting strophe when you load the page?

Comment: That just keeps Strophe from sending requests. How are you loading pages? Are these new pages or new content on an existing page? Pausing on unload shouldn't have anything to do with loading on a new page. But if that works...

Comment: i have above code under the page load if localStorage has the RID and SID then it will simply call attach , but it doesnt work everytime

Comment: "under the page load" - are you sure all the scripts are done loading every time? You should be initlaizing from a $(document).ready or $(window).load function.

Comment: not working for me too, if I pass same rid, request is `<body rid='100594016' xmlns='http://jabber.org/protocol/httpbind' sid='6c573f67'/>` and I get response `<body xmlns="http://jabber.org/protocol/httpbind" type="terminate" condition="item-not-found"></body>` If I increment rid, I get 400 not found

Comment: "if I pass same rid" - you MUST increment the RID. Add 1 to the value. If that doesn't work, create a new question with your code. The code you including doesn't show you trying to attach.